# Calculating overlapping and non-continuous time in DAX

Tags: dax

I have a table listing certain events, let's call them incidents and outages.  One incident can have multiple outages.  Outage start and end times can be overlapping and/or non-continuous, for example something like this:

```
AssetID | Incident ID | Outage ID | Start time | End time | Outage Length
A       |           1 |         1 |       7:00 |     9:00 |      2
A       |           1 |         2 |       8:00 |     9:00 |      1
A       |           1 |         3 |       8:30 |    11:00 |      2.5
A       |           1 |         4 |      13:00 |    15:00 |      2
```

The total length of an incident should be a total of all outages excluding overlapping and non-outages times.  In the example above it should be 2 + 0 (fully overlapping with the previous incident)+ 2 (partially overlapping) + 2 (no overlap with previous outages).

Is there a simple-ish way to create a measure to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this resource](https://www.pbiusergroup.com/discussion/n) and it seems to be working I think.

It uses a helper table:

```
 TimeTable = GENERATESERIES(min('Table'[Start]),MAX('Table'[End]),60/(60*60*24))
```

Which in turn is used by a measure:

```
 Measure = SUMX(ADDCOLUMNS(
            VALUES(TimeTable[Value]),
            "Count of ranges",
                var _time = TimeTable[Value] return
                    if(CALCULATE(
                        COUNTROWS('Table'),
                        _time < 'Table'[End] && _time >= 'Table'[Start])>=1,1)),[Count of ranges])+0
```

In effect it creates a one dimensional solution to the two dimensional problem of overlapping events:

[image]

This seems to be working for now I think. Have to apply it to real life data but looking at the test data it appears to work.  I think this is a very neat solution:

[image]

I think I've managed to solve the problem for now!